# Invalid opcode OR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') (depending on the situation)

Tags: web3js, javascript, contract-invocation

I'm working on a bot that loads in a bunch of values from an array and uses an event handler to take action upon an event.  This was originally built as a bot to monitor a swap on two exchanges for a single token pair and I have been reworking it.  When an event happens, it runs through a few different functions, one of which is `determineProfitability` where I am encountering kind of a double error, neither of which I know how to fix exactly.  Here's the relevant code for the bot:

```
const arbAgainst = ["obj1","obj2","obj3"]

const main = () => {
   const mainPromises = arbAgainst.map(async (object, i) => {

      //some other declarations

      uPair.events.Swap({}, async () => {
         // This sends users to the lower async functions when a swap occurs
      }
      sPair.events.Swap({}, async () => {
         // This sends users to the lower async functions when a swap occurs
      }
   }
}

// other functions

const determineProfitability = async (_routerPath, _token0Contract, _token0, _token1, uPair, sPair) => {
   let reserves, exchangeToBuy, exchangeToSell, reserve0, reserve1

   if (_routerPath[0]._address == uRouter._address) {
       reserves = await getReserves(sPair, false)

       exchangeToBuy = 'Uniswap'
       exchangeToSell = 'Sushiswap'

   } else {
      reserves = await getReserves(uPair, true)

      exchangeToBuy = 'Sushiswap'
      exchangeToSell = 'Uniswap'
   }

      //A few other things happen

   try {
      let result = await _routerPath[1].methods.getAmountsIn(reserves[0], [_token0.address, _token1.address]).call()

      const token0In = result[0] 
      const token1In = result[1] 

      result = await _routerPath[1].methods.getAmountsOut(token1In, [_token1.address, _token0.address]).call()
      
      //Other code
   }
}
```

The issue seems to occur specifically in this line: `let result = await _routerPath[1].methods.getAmountsIn(reserves[0], [_token0.address, _token1.address]).call()` at the `reserves[0]`. This is the error stack:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at ABICoder.formatParam (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:230:30)
    at /Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:99:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ABICoder.encodeParameters (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:93:21)
    at /Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:463:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object._encodeMethodABI (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:462:8)
    at Object._processExecuteArguments (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:726:39)
    at Object._executeMethod (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:745:68)
    at determineProfitability (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/bot.js:194:121)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Subscription.callback (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/bot.js:59:42)
```

However, if I decide instead to change `reserves[0]` in that line to `reserves.reserve0` I get this error stack:

```
Error: Returned error: invalid opcode: INVALID
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at Object.callback (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:300:36)
    at /Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/index.js:114:45
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at WebsocketProvider._onMessage (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/index.js:102:69)
    at W3CWebSocket._dispatchEvent [as dispatchEvent] (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/yaeti/lib/EventTarget.js:115:12)
    at W3CWebSocket.onMessage (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:234:14)
    at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:205:19)
    at WebSocketConnection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at WebSocketConnection.processFrame (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:554:26)
    at /Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:323:40
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  data: null
}
```

I traced the problem, per the stack, back to this bit of code inside `web3-eth-abi` but I'm honestly not sure why it's erroring here.  This is the code I'm referencing (specifically the line `if (size / 8 < param.length) {`)

```
ABICoder.prototype.formatParam = function (type, param) {
    const paramTypeBytes = new RegExp(/^bytes([0-9]*)$/);
    const paramTypeBytesArray = new RegExp(/^bytes([0-9]*)\[\]$/);
    const paramTypeNumber = new RegExp(/^(u?int)([0-9]*)$/);
    const paramTypeNumberArray = new RegExp(/^(u?int)([0-9]*)\[\]$/);
    // Format BN to string
    if (utils.isBN(param) || utils.isBigNumber(param)) {
        return param.toString(10);
    }
    if (type.match(paramTypeBytesArray) || type.match(paramTypeNumberArray)) {
        return param.map(p => this.formatParam(type.replace('[]', ''), p));
    }
    // Format correct width for u?int[0-9]*
    let match = type.match(paramTypeNumber);
    if (match) {
        let size = parseInt(match[2] || "256");
        if (size / 8 < param.length) {
            // pad to correct bit width
            param = utils.leftPad(param, size);
        }
    }
    // Format correct length for bytes[0-9]+
    match = type.match(paramTypeBytes);
    if (match) {
        if (Buffer.isBuffer(param)) {
            param = utils.toHex(param);
        }
        // format to correct length
        let size = parseInt(match[1]);
        if (size) {
            let maxSize = size * 2;
            if (param.substring(0, 2) === '0x') {
                maxSize += 2;
            }
            if (param.length < maxSize) {
                // pad to correct length
                param = utils.rightPad(param, size * 2);
            }
        }
        // format odd-length bytes to even-length
        if (param.length % 2 === 1) {
            param = '0x0' + param.substring(2);
        }
    }
    return param;
};
```

Would love any guidance here!

Update: I've determined this is related somehow to the way the number is passed into `getAmountsIn`.  The parameter requires a uint, but then there's the length issue.  It isn't clear to me the expected length so I'm not sure how to fix the issue at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `BigInt()` to pass the reserves as an integer that wasn't truncated by scientific exponential representation and that made it possible to pass this issue.

```
reserve0 = reserves.reserve0;
reserve0toNumber = BigInt(reserve0)
reserve0Final = reserve0toNumber

   try {

      let result = await _routerPath[0].methods.getAmountsIn(reserve0Final, [_token0.address, _token1.address]).call()

      // Other code
   }
```